# How can I skip Github Actions step if commit author is in a Github Team?

Tags: github-actions

We have a controversial step in our CI which some people find useful and others feel is a bit noisy.

I would like to skip this step if a committer is in a github team called something like "Don't run the summary step".

Even better, it would be great to change `comment_mode: "failures"` to off for users in the Github Team we create, so they still get enriched unit test failure info, but don't get the comment on their PR.

```yaml
    - name: Publish test results
      uses: EnricoMi/publish-unit-test-result-action@v2
      if: always()
      with:
        junit_files: "tmp/jest*.xml"
        comment_mode: "failures"
        check_name: "Javascript jest tests"
```

Comment: You can utilize https://github.com/tspascoal/get-user-teams-membership and then use its output to set an env var e.g. `COMMENT_MODE` to be later used as `comment_mode: ${{ env.COMMENT_MODE }}`.

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I think you need to develop your own github action or have something like Jenkins to better control and do it whatever you need

Comment: thanks.  Azeem your suggestion worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to [Azeem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7670262/azeem) I have a working solution:

```yaml
env:
  TEST_SUMMARY_COMMENT_MODE: "failures"
jobs:
  set_test_summary_comment_mode:
    name: set_test_summary_comment_mode
    runs-on: ubuntu
    steps:
    - name: Check if user is a member of the team
      uses: tspascoal/get-user-teams-membership@v2
      id: checkUserMember
      with:
        username: ${{ github.actor }}
        team: 'Suppress PR test summary comments'
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

    - name: Set publish test results comment_mode flag to suppress comments on PR if there are failures
      if: ${{ steps.checkUserMember.outputs.isTeamMember == 'true' }}
      run:  echo "TEST_SUMMARY_COMMENT_MODE='off'" >> $GITHUB_ENV

    - run: echo "COMMENT_MODE for EnricoMi/publish-unit-test-result-action [${{ env.TEST_SUMMARY_COMMENT_MODE }}]"

  build:
    ...
    - name: Publish test results
      uses: EnricoMi/publish-unit-test-result-action@v2
      if: always()
      with:
        junit_files: "tmp/jest*.xml"
        comment_mode: ${{ env.TEST_SUMMARY_COMMENT_MODE }}
        check_name: "Javascript jest tests"
```